# Get JSON Object by string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wrote a function which take an id of the link as a name of JSON dataset.

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    var dataset = $(this).attr("id");
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
        chart.series[i].setData(lata.dataset[i].data);
    }
});
```

But in this case *dataset* is string and it doesn't works. So how to get object from JSON file by string?

Comment: how big is this JSON data set that you are storing in the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[]` operator:

```
chart.series[i].setData(lata[dataset][i].data);
```

`foo['bar']` and `foo.bar` are equivalent - except the fact that `[]` takes an *expression* and thus allows you to use e.g.  a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.series[i].setData(lata[dataset][i].data);
```

this would be valid even if `dataset` is nto a valid identifier like `"a b"`